# Single word for receiving donation and/or loan

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (if one exists) that can be used to describe an action of receiving a donation or loan.

I thought about (something like) monetary but I am not sure that is correct as monetary may be to vague in my case. It needs to be able to be used to describe receiving of either a donation or a loan.

Answer (score 1):

With certain organizations, it is known as a monetary *infusion*.

Answer (score 0):

***[Injection](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/injection)*** (Collins)

countable noun

> An injection of money or resources into an organization is the act of
>   providing it with more money or resources, to help it become
>   more efficient or profitable.
>
> [business]
>
> An injection of cash is needed to fund some of these projects.
>
> The company is hoping to obtain a £250 million cash injection from the
>   government

This is better than the more frequently used word *investment* because *investment* has the idea of expecting a return, which is an idea that is not in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You ***Benefit*** from having a benefactor.

> ***[Benefit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/benefit)***- An advantage or profit gained from something.